# Refused to connect to data:text/html;charset=utf8 in iOS Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, content-security-policy

I am developing a web app in Angular, HTML and Bootstrap.
When launching this web app in Chrome & android, it loads the elements like the modal, texts, select option.
It works perfectly in chrome, but when using Safari in iPhone Device OS 10
An error in web inspector error appears.

```
Refused to connect to data:text/html;charset=utf-8;%3Cbody%3E%3Cremove%3E%3C/remove%3E%3Ch5
```

This the code in angular:
App Module HTML:

```
<app-modal-terms [labelValues]="labelValues"></app-modal-terms>
```

App Module component:

```
this.labelValues = "<div><div><p>Paragraph test</p>"
```

AppModalTerms component:

```
<div [innerHTML]="labelValues"></div>
```

I tried to search here, it says that it has something to do with duplicate Content Security Policy. However, when I checked this is in our side, there is only 1 Content Security Policy defined.

**Angular Version used:  7.2.15**

I hope someone can give me some light. :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a practical solution to this however it seems related to this discussion;
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16503

We've had the same issue with certain versions of 10.3. The workaround (whilst not ideal) is to update your CSP to include the data src;

> connect-src data:

Comment: True, we hold off our release for this. Because of this issue.